# Override padding in smaller devices React material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a grid of column 3,6,3 & I have also given a grid spacing of 3.

For lg, md screen devices sizes it looks okay i.e spacing between grid. But when I reduce the screen size spacing between Grid remains the same which does not look okay

What I want is spacing between Grid for lg & md devices to be 3 but for sm & xs devices to be 0 so I don't see any padding around Grid.

I have inspected the DOM & have seen padding to be 12px for Grid spacing 3.

I have tried this

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  ..., // Other default things
  overrides: {
    MuiGrid: {
      'spacing-xs-3': {
        '& > $item': {
          padding: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This does the job of removing padding which is none obviously but for all device sizes but I want this padding to be removed only for smaller size devices.

I used this inside the component like this

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
     ...,
     overrides: { // This part , I tried both with and without overrides key
       MuiGrid: {
        'spacing-xs-3': {
          '& > $item': {
            [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
              padding: 'none',
            }
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }));
```

None really seems to work, Where am I making mistake?

Comment: Please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem. This will make it considerably easier/faster to provide you with the correct syntax. Decide which way you would prefer to change this (in the theme vs. in the component) and use that approach in the sandbox.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use `$root` element instead of `$item`, like this

```
MuiGrid: {
            'spacing-xs-3': {
                '& > $root': {
                   [Your styles go here]
                },
            },
        },
```